# What do they do if confirmed positive during US airport COVID-19 testing?

Tags: safety, tsa, covid-19

Is there a known policy for what U.S. airport/government employees will do if they test somebody for COVID-19 and find them positive?

Further, is this policy dependent upon airport, state, country, etc? i.e. is there no strict 1 federal code?

Please explain/link to sources if anyone has any information.

Comment: Any test cannot return an immediate result.  I believe the quickest test currently is less than 1 day.  Therefore, the only thing they can do is look for symptoms such as a high temperature, cough, etc. and then act accordingly.

Comment: I am not from the US, where I am now if they decided to test you then you either will be asked to self-isolate, or be quarantined at a hospital if you show symptoms. Once the result is out, you either be released or admitted to hospital if positive.

Comment: @SDH As well as bill you for the test?

Comment: All I could find was https://www.dhs.gov/news/2020/03/13/fact-sheet-dhs-notice-arrival-restrictions-china-iran-and-schengen-countries-europe which doesn’t cover action on cases identified during screening as far as I can see. It may get updated, I guess

Comment: @jason.kaisersmith SG have 3-6 hour test - https://www.todayonline.com/singapore/covid-19-new-swab-test-travellers-entering-singapore-moh-warns-new-waves-infection

Comment: The guys at the airport are just Q&A screening: "Do you have fever?" "Do you have cough?" "Do you have shortness of breath?"

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the pandemic is now over.